Post-apocalyptic horror/thriller movie set in a building with puzzle rooms and killer dogs
This will be very hard to know, just because of how BAD my memory is. I watched this movie when I was REALLY young. I can't remember anything other then small snippets and not even that well. I just know it was scary and I wanna watch it again.

It's based in a huge building.

There are multiple people stuck in this building and the main character was a man, I think.

Seems post-apocalyptic with something with a virus?

For some reason, they needed to go somewhere in the building.

In one scene, someone was in a room that seemed to be high-tech and tried to solve a puzzle to get through.

And at some point, there were some killer dogs (robots or infected, I
can't remember).

At the end, they get an antidote of some kind.


The film is not:

Resident Evil (2002)


Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you be more specific about when you watched this?

Can you rule out any movies with a similar premise? Resident Evil (2002), for example?

Following up on Fez's comments... how long ago was this? If I saw something when I was really young, we're talking late 60s/70s. To others on here it would be the 90s/00s. Would help us narrow it down a bit.

Could this be Maze Runner?

Is it possible that you are combining aspects of Resident Evil (already provided as an answer) and Cube in your memory?

Is this Resident Evil (2002)...?

A special military unit fights a powerful, out-of-control supercomputer and hundreds of scientists who have mutated into flesh-eating creatures after a laboratory accident.

What matches:

The plot involves several people entering a tall building with many levels (most of which are underground) and getting trapped within it.
A genetically-engineered virus called the T-virus has been released within the building, turning the people who were already in it into bloodthirsty zombies.
Some dobermanns were in the building and they get turned into bloodthirsty zombie dogs.
The building is very high-tech, with an AI controlling it, and one specific corridor that can slice anyone in it apart with laser beams.

What doesn't match:

The main protagonist is female, although there are male supporting characters.
I don't know if there were any puzzle rooms, per se.





OP could be remembering things like the laser grid as puzzle rooms. I don't remember a moth though.

@moopet - I thought that part of the description likely involved one or more typos. After all, the OP typed "snip bits" when they presumably meant snippets, and the word "moth" itself looks a bit out of place in that sentence.

I think the sentence with those words is " I can’t remember anything other than small snippets and not even that well"

Hi! OP here, this is similar to what the movie was about but resident evil isn’t it.
But I can remember at the end they get an antidote of some kind, I’d like to mention they are STUCK in the building too. I appreciate the guess!!

@Izabella - The main characters in Resident Evil were trapped in the building (called the Hive) for most of the film as well, since the AI controlling the Hive sealed it to contain the T-virus. They also found an antidote for the T-virus near the end. But I'll update your question to reflect what you've said here.
